# Reusing existing types in classic XML Web Services

Tags: visual-studio-2008, asp.net-2.0, webservice-client

How can I reuse existing class library types in a generated web service proxy, in Visual Studio 2008 "old-school" XML Web Service reference?

Thx

Comment: Possibly your easiest option is to modify the genrated proxy, change the namespaces in it (so that return types and parameters are now using the class definitions that you want to reuse), and eliminate any duplicate class definitions.